# Java applications crash on Linux in 3 hours

Tags: java, linux, jvm, centos

I've created 10 test applications in Java to try them on my Linux CentOS server with Java 64bit.

For example an application creates a file called test.txt via `FileWriter`. It creates an infinite loop and it writes a word in the file once a second. It's pretty easy.

The problem is that **it works for about 2-3 hours and then it stops**. Then I have to relaunch it again. I see no coredump file or logs, so I don't know what is happening.

I use this code to launch it as root:

```
java -Xmx4000M -jar test.jar
```

Should I give any special permissions to the JVM?

My dedicated server has 16Gb of free RAM at the moment. I also tested a very complex Java app (website crawler with many functions) that uses about 1Gb of Ram on my laptop and I see the same exact behaviour. It crashes after 2-3 hours...

Comment: How much memory do you have?  Linux can kill off high resource using processes if you are low on resources.  This is not based on permissions.  BTW The default heap size which is 1/4 of main memory might be a better size to use and less likely to be killed off.

Comment: If you write 1000 words per second it crash in 10 seconds?

Comment: See the memory management. what is happening when you close the file writer/buffer and open it again next time (in 10 seconds)

Comment: You could add a `try-catch` block for anything `Throwable` (even `Errors`) to see if it's an `OutOfMemory`

Comment: If it's not seeing any log files or dumps, then it's because your program is not writing any.  Put in trace statements to view progress, and yes, use @Albert 's idea to catch the actual error and write out information at that point.

Comment: What does `ulimit -t` show? Anything in `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Comment: I did `ulimit -c unlimited` but now it crashes after a few minutes only :S

Comment: Please post the complete source code of a test application showing this behaviour.